# Parse JSON multi dimensional data for one output

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse this data through JQuery:

http://www.mycurrency.net/service/rates

I want to search through it, find a matching country code that I will have stored in a variable called 'code' and then return the rate for that country.

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, I've looked through the answers and they were either too complex or too simple.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = '[{"currency_code":"AED","rate":3.6727,"code":"AE","name":"United Arab Emirates"},{"currency_code":"AFN","rate":68.51,"code":"AF","name":"Afghanistan"},{"currency_code":"ALL","rate":111.55,"code":"AL","name":"Albania"},{"currency_code":"AMD","rate":477.85,"code":"AM","name":"Armenia"},{"currency_code":"ANG","rate":1.7775,"code":"AW","name":"Aruba"},{"currency_code":"AOA","rate":165.096,"code":"AO","name":"Angola"}]'
var Code="AW";
$.each(jQuery.parseJSON(json),function(key,value){
  if(value.code==Code)
   $("body").append("<span> "+value.currency_code+" |</span><span> "+value.rate+" |</span><span> "+value.code+" |</span><span> "+value.name+" </span><hr>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Var Code ;  
var Result = new FromData();
 $.each(yourjsonfile, function (key, value) {
        if (youjsonfile.Code = Code)
Result.append(key, value);
    });
```

i dont have much experience also i cant comment but have you tried this ? 
this is going to loop over you data compare the code and append it to you formdata var then you can post that by ajax

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the following code. Hope that helps. You can fetch the data in as array of objects and then apply map and reduce to find the required key. I have just copied sample data from the URL and prepared this small snippet.

```js
data = [{
  "currency_code": "AED",
  "rate": 3.6727,
  "code": "AE",
  "name": "United Arab Emirates"
}, {
  "currency_code": "AFN",
  "rate": 68.4958,
  "code": "AF",
  "name": "Afghanistan"
}, {
  "currency_code": "ALL",
  "rate": 111.5,
  "code": "AL",
  "name": "Albania"
}, {
  "currency_code": "AMD",
  "rate": 477.85,
  "code": "AM",
  "name": "Armenia"
}, {
  "currency_code": "ANG",
  "rate": 1.7775,
  "code": "AW",
  "name": "Aruba"
}, {
  "currency_code": "AOA",
  "rate": 165.096,
  "code": "AO",
  "name": "Angola"
}];


code = 'AE';
arr = [];

arr = data.map(function(e) {
  if (e.code == code)
    return e.rate;
}).reduce(function(accumulator, value) {

  if (value == undefined)
    return accumulator;
  else
    return value;
});


console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sq8vfx0x/1/

```
<p class="code"></div>
<p class="rate"></div>

var o = [
{"currency_code":"AED","rate":3.6727,"code":"AE","name":"United Arab Emirates"},
{"currency_code":"AFN","rate":68.5003,"code":"AF","name":"Afghanistan"},
{"currency_code":"ALL","rate":111.479,"code":"AL","name":"Albania"},
{"currency_code":"AMD","rate":477.85,"code":"AM","name":"Armenia"}
];

var searchCode = 'AF';
var code;
for(var x = 0; x < o.length; x++){
    if(o[x].code == searchCode){
        code = o[x].code;
        $('.rate').append('<p>' + o[x].rate + '</p>');
    }
}
$('.code').append('<p>' + code + '</p>');
```